# How to use composer/composer PHP classes to update individual packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to use the composer/composer PHP classes to update individual plugin packages.
I do not want to use command-line solutions like exec("php composer.phar update");

I am unable to get it to work. I have tried several different options, much alike the following code.
It just returns a blank screen.

```
    use Composer\Console\Application;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

    $input = new ArrayInput(array('command' => 'require vendor/packkage dev-master'));
    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application = new Application();

    $application->run($input, $output);
    dd($output->fetch());
```

Things i would like to achieve:

- Download/Update individual packages
- Get result output to verify success
- Dump autoload
- Remove/require packages

A bit of context details:

I am creating a plugin updater for my PHP application (in admin panel).
Every plugin is a composer package and resides on my own Satis repository.
The plugins get installed into a custom dir using my composer plugin.
I can read composer.lock locally and packages.json on the satis server to figure out 
what packages require updates.

**update**
I've managed to at least get it to work. The no-output issue was due to $application->setAutoExit that needed to be false before running. Next issue that i had was that the required package would download itself into the same directory as the class where i called it from. Solved that by using putenv and chdir. Result:

root/comp.php

```
putenv('COMPOSER_HOME=' . __DIR__ . '/vendor/bin/composer');
chdir(__DIR__);
```

root/workbench/sumvend/sumpack/src/PackageManager.php

```
include(base_path() . '/comp.php');
$input = new ArrayInput(array('command' => 'require', 'packages' => ['vend/pak dev-master']));
$output = new BufferedOutput();
$application = new Application();

$application->setAutoExit(false);
$application->run($input, $output); //, $output);
dd($output->fetch());
```

This works, but it's far from ideal.

Comment: Well, `It just returns a blank screen` != sufficient info. You **have** to find out what happens by inspecting your server logs, if the browser can't display any information whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full solution to this would be pretty long winded, but I will try to get you on the right track.

```
php composer.phar require composer/composer dev-master
```

You can load the source of composer into your project vendors.  You might have already done this.

The code you are looking for is at: `Composer\Command\RequireCommand`.

```
$install = Installer::create($io, $composer);

$install
    ->setVerbose($input->getOption('verbose'))
    ->setPreferSource($input->getOption('prefer-source'))
    ->setPreferDist($input->getOption('prefer-dist'))
    ->setDevMode($updateDevMode)
    ->setUpdate(true)
    ->setUpdateWhitelist(array_keys($requirements))
    ->setWhitelistDependencies($input->getOption('update-with-dependencies'));
;

$status = $install->run();
```

Most of the command relates to the reading and writing to of the `composer.json` file.
However the installer itself is independent of where the configuration actually came from.  You could in theory store the configuration in a database.

This is the static create method for the installer:

```
public static function create(IOInterface $io, Composer $composer)
{
    return new static(
        $io,
        $composer->getConfig(),
        $composer->getPackage(),
        $composer->getDownloadManager(),
        $composer->getRepositoryManager(),
        $composer->getLocker(),
        $composer->getInstallationManager(),
        $composer->getEventDispatcher(),
        $composer->getAutoloadGenerator()
    );
}
```

You will need to pay special attention to the `Package`,  And implement your own.

Although your current attempt to run it on the command line will work, I do not recommend it because Composer is primarily a development and deployment utility, not an application utility.

In order to smoothly use it to assist with loading plugins on a production environment, you will need to tightly integrate its internals with your own application, not just use it on the side.

This is something I am interested in as well, and I think this has inspired me to look into it myself.  So I'll let you know what I come up with, but this is the best I can advise you for now on what I consider to be the correct approach.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies it a bit for me. This approach certainly looks better. I'll have a go at it